# How to set variable and use them for select statement in Oracle PL/SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

I tried this code in Oracle SQL Developer and return an error "an INTO clause is expected in this SELECT statement"

```
declare 
flag_id_header int;
begin

select NVM(MAX(A.ID),0) as VAL into flag_id_header from TBL_FUNDING_HEADER A;
flag_id_header := flag_id_header + 1;

select flag_id_header, B.DATE_OF_TRANSACTION
from TBL_FUNDING_SOURCE B
;

end;
```

In Sql Server I can do this very easily

```
declare @var1 int = 1;

select @var1, col1, col2, col3 from tbl_whatever
```

I need this select before insert them into temporary table.

Comment: What do you want to achieve?

Comment: put the variable into select statement and insert them into temporary table as I said. I need a static value for the variable to be selected

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `MAX` to find the next value in a sequence; if you have two users running concurrent statements then they will both get the same value and you will have duplicate entries.

Use a sequence.

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE flag_id_header__seq;
```

Then increment the sequence and insert:

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id YOUR_TEMP_TABLE.COLUMN1%TYPE;
BEGIN
  -- Set the variable to the next sequence value.
  v_id := flag_id_header__seq.NEXTVAL;

  -- Use the sequence value in the insert.
  INSERT INTO your_temp_table (column1, column2)
  SELECT v_id,
         DATE_OF_TRANSACTION
  FROM   TBL_FUNDING_SOURCE;
END;
/
```

---

> I think I forgot to mention that there are `TBL_FUNDING_HEADER` to be inserted first to get the ID (it is `INT PK AUTO INCREMENT`), and then I need the ID selected with `TBL_FUNDING_SOURCE` to be inserted into `TBL_FUNDING` as FK

Oracle does not support `AUTO_INCREMENT`; you need to use `GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY`.

If you want to insert into an `IDENTITY` column and then use that later, then use a `RETURNING` clause with the initial `INSERT`.

```sql
DECLARE
  v_id TBL_FUNDING_HEADER.ID%TYPE;
BEGIN
  INSERT INTO TBL_FUNDING_HEADER (column1)
  VALUES ('something')
  RETURNING id INTO v_id;

  -- Then use the returned identity value in the insert.
  INSERT INTO your_temp_table (column1, column2)
  SELECT v_id,
         DATE_OF_TRANSACTION
  FROM   TBL_FUNDING_SOURCE;
END;
/
```

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/yFn-gzBK)

Comment: I think I forgot to mention that there are TBL_FUNDING_HEADER to be inserted first to get the ID (it is INT PK AUTO INCREMENT), and then I need the ID selected with TBL_FUNDING_SOURCE to be inserted into TBL_FUNDING as FK

Comment: @RonT Use `INSERT ... RETURNING ... INTO ...` to get the `id` value rather than trying to get the maximum value from the table.

Comment: my bad, my brain still in sql server mode.. and yes as u said, I did create the table using GENERATED ALWAYS AS IDENTITY earlier, I keep mention AUTO_INCREMENT by mistake. I think my problem now solved by your script above... Thank you sir.